# Can't see any "require" or "include" command in joomla php files

Tags: php, joomla, path, include, require

There is a lot of php files in joomla folders and I dont know where they are belong?! There is no "include" or "require" command in them. How Does joomla relate php files togather?

Comment: Take a look in the documentation (Which is pretty bad) and in the files there are include, require and so on!

Comment: Where is this documentation??!! Sorry for very basic question. I have searched all the files for "include" and "require" and didn't find any thing

Comment: Google ("joomla doc") :D link: https://docs.joomla.org/ Here you find the documentation for beginners, administrators and developers!